# xr-hyper link color does not follow hypersetup

Tags: hyperref, color

I am using the `xr-hyper` package to reference labels in another document. The linking is working properly. However, I noticed that colors of the `xr-hyper`links are not following the colors defined in `\hypersetup`.

Is there anyway to adjust the color of a link created with the `xr-hyper` package?

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured it out after a bit more testing. The proper command inside  `hypersetup` is `filecolor` per:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Customization